# Are different color fills of curve items possible in ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a single curve with circle points. Is it possible to set CurveItemPoints to a different fill color? I would set significantly points to different colors.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: no.

To do similar stuff I created additional `SymbolObj` class and added objects of that class to the pane to mark some significant points.

Here's some code for that:

```
internal class SymbolObj : ZedGraph.GraphObj
{
    private ZedGraph.Symbol symbol;

    public SymbolObj(ZedGraph.SymbolType type, Color color, PointF position, float size)
    {
        this.symbol = new ZedGraph.Symbol(type, color);
        this.symbol.Size = size;
        if((type== SymbolType.Plus || type == SymbolType.Star || type== SymbolType.HDash || type == SymbolType.XCross || type == SymbolType.VDash) && size >= 4)
            this.symbol.Border.Width = 3f;
        this.symbol.Fill.IsVisible = true;
        this.symbol.Fill.Color = color;
        this.Location.X = position.X;
        this.Location.Y = position.Y;
    }

    public SymbolObj(SymbolObj rhs)
        : base(rhs)
    {
        this.symbol = new Symbol(rhs.symbol);
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g, ZedGraph.PaneBase pane, float scaleFactor)
    {
        if (((GraphPane)pane).XAxis.Type == AxisType.Text)
        {
            if (Location.X > 0)
            {
                var xx = new double[(int)Location.X];
                var yy = new double[(int)Location.X];

                for (int i = 0; i < Location.X; i++)
                {
                    xx[i] = i;
                    yy[i] = double.NegativeInfinity;

                }
                yy[yy.Count() - 1] = Location.Y;
                LineItem line = new LineItem("Symbol", xx, yy, symbol.Fill.Color, SymbolType.None);
                symbol.Draw(g, (GraphPane)pane, line, scaleFactor, false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LineItem line = new LineItem("Symbol", new double[] { Location.X }, new double[] { Location.Y }, symbol.Fill.Color, SymbolType.None);
            symbol.Draw(g, (GraphPane)pane, line, scaleFactor, false);
        }
    }

    public override void GetCoords(ZedGraph.PaneBase pane, Graphics g, float scaleFactor, out string shape, out string coords)
    {
        shape = "point";
        coords = this.Location.X.ToString() + ", " + this.Location.Y.ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You should accept my answer if it helped you, upvote if you find it valuable etc. That is the custom of stackoverflow :)